# Destroy Facebook session completely in a custom Android Application using Facebook SDK 4.x.x

Tags: android, facebook, session, logout, android-facebook

I am just new to Android Application and trying my hands on implementing Facebook login within my app. Successfully implementation of login but logout causes some trouble.
The first time I logged in it requested for my details and then signed in.
Next time I do the same it no more asks for my details, by default it logs me in with account.

What if I want to sign in with different user?

I have searched the net for solution and found out that -
- I cannot use Session as they were available only till Facebook SDK 3.X.X not for SDK 4.X.X
- I have tried calling `LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();`
(But I still have doubts where to use it.)
- I have also tried

```
new GraphRequest(AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),"/me/permissions/", null, HttpMethod.DELETE,
                new GraphRequest.Callback(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted(GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                        LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
                    }
                }).executeAsync();
```

- and I have also tried doing this :

` AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
  Account[] localAccounts = am.getAccounts();

```
    for (int i=0; i<localAccounts.length; i++){
        if (localAccounts[i].type.equals("com.facebook.auth.login")){
            am.removeAccount(localAccounts[i], null, null);
        }
    }`
```

So it'll be really great if somebody could guide me properly on how to carry out a successful logout operation on Facebook, I'll be highly obliged.
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The SDK will use either of two options to let the user log in to your app on Android:

1. using the native login dialog (which is powered by the Facebook app that is installed on the device)
2. using a webview-based dialog if the Facebook app is not installed on the device.

Both options depend on you being signed into Facebook in another app (your browser/your native Facebook app).
If you want to log into your app as a different user (there is really no need, because android system user profiles should be considered personal and individually owned), you need to go to the app you use for Facebook (native Facebook app/browser) and switch to a different profile there. After that you should be able to log into your app with that other profile.

Other than that, it is not your app's job to log people out of their Facebook.